# ConstraintLayout positioning doesn’t work

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

When I drag an item into a ConstraintLayout in Android Studio, it goes directly to the top of the layout and I can't move it until I put the constraints on it. I want to turn on design time position.

This is what I want:

[image]

When I add an item inside constraint layout, there is always a default location in the top:

[image]

I searched everywhere and I couldn’t find any solution. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constraint layout design time position didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599918/constraint-layout-design-time-position-didnt-work)

Comment: no i still searching for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your pc region format to English
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8oGP.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).